# android-gallery how to set the position of the child which is selected

Tags: android, view, position, gallery

as we know,the default position of the child which is selected is in the middle.but i want to show it in the gallery's left.how to do this.

thanks~

Answer (score 7):

use the method setSelection(int position) to set which item will be shown as selected. For showing the left you have just use setSelection(0). simple... please check the given link by [Rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573700/rahul) for more information about Gallery